# Angular 2/5 append material dom to form

Tags: angular

I have a html file which contains some angular material stuff. On buttonclick I wants to add this contant to my form. Is that possible?
The issue is that I add only the raw html which i need before angular render the material contant.

txt.html:

```
<mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
    <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
</mat-card-actions>
```

form.componant.ts

```
@ViewChild('one') d1: ElementRef;
txt = require('./txt.html');
public add(){
  this.d1.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', this.txt);
}
```

form.componant.html:

```
<form>
  <section #one></section>
</form>
```

I guess I have to compile the page again. I tried it with ng-change:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-model="demo" ng-change="comp();">
```

I found a Solution based on this tutorial:
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Do you want to add the `mat-card` component to the `form` component based on some condition?

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` is AngularJS code and will not work in Angular version 2+.

Comment: @Narm yes you are right. my mistake. i tried to detect a changing inside of my body to emit angular material again. But I use Angular 5. So this way makes no sense

Comment: @bugs inside of the content are only dom elements which i reach by classname if i submit my form. Currently all functionalities works fine. But If i click on button i add a raw card element without angular material css

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you want this content to be dynamically injected, and not just hidden instead? You could just as easily set a show variable:

```
<mat-card-actions *ngIf="showLikeShareButtons">
    <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
    <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
</mat-card-actions>
```

then inside your component:

```
export class ..... {
    public showLikeShareButtons = false;


    public add() { this.showLikeShareButtons = true; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don´t know how many times i will add this card. Thats why this doesn´t works :(

Comment: @NicoSchuck so this card can be added any number of times by a user depending on their actions?

Comment: @SyntaticFrucose you are right. most times it will be less than 10 times. But sometimes it possible that someone adds up to 40-50 times for reasons. If I use this way i load everytime a huge overhead.

Comment: Sounds like something you should use Dynamic components for then, there are lots of resources online about these

Comment: sounds like the right way. i will try and repost if i found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

To add dom to already existing form, you can bind the content to DIV. Refer the following code snippet:

form.componant.html:

```
<form>
  <section #one>
      <div [innerHtml]="txt | keepHtml: 'html'"></div>
  </section>
</form>
```

Create a new pipe safe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';


@Pipe({ name: 'keepHtml', pure: false })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
}

public transform(value: string, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
switch (type) {
    case 'html':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    case 'style':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
    case 'script':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
    case 'url':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
    case 'resourceUrl':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
    default:
        throw new Error(`Unable to bypass security for invalid type: ${type}`);
}
}
}
```

Note: Don't forget to add the pipe to your app modules.

form.componant.ts

```
@ViewChild('one') d1: ElementRef;
public add(){
    txt = require('./txt.html');
}
```

Comment: If the above does not work, you're going to need to use Dynamic Components. This article will get you started: https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e

Comment: hey i tried your way. Unfortunately i still get mat-card without material css. Thank you for the LINK